# REDIS: Automatically set expiry of newly added keys

Tags: lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm currently researching redis in how to make more efficient use of it.

After researching on the internet, I see that one of the ways to make efficient use of Redis is to set expiry times onto all the keys created on the server.
I'm currently loading data from a Java program into Redis, however rather than setting the `EXPIRE` command from the Java program, I'd like to set the expiry of all keys on server-side.

I was wondering whether there is any way of setting any new KEYS (or all keys) added to the REDIS server with an expiry time of 10 minutes. Currently, the `EXPIRE` command requires you to provide a specific key.

One idea I had is to create a LUA script which scans all the keys with a TTL. If the TTL is -1, then set the expiry. This script would have to have to run periodically though.

Another question, is that is there a better/ efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the other answers, if you're only looking to save the extra command, and you're only doing basic `SET`s, then there is the `SETEX` command that is a combination `SET` and `EXPIRE` that might be what you're looking for.

https://redis.io/commands/setex

`SETEX key seconds value`

Answer (score 2):

You can set a memory limit and all keys will be evicted when that limit is reached. This may or may not answer your question since you don't actually control the TTL

From the [docs](https://redis.io/topics/config):

> If you plan to use Redis just as a cache where every key will have an
>    expire set, you may consider using the following configuration instead
>    (assuming a max memory limit of 2 megabytes as an example):
>
> ```
> maxmemory 2mb
> maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
> ```

See also the detailed instructions on [Using Redis as an LRU cache](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache): it suggests that `allkeys-lru` is more memory efficient than setting an expire. From that same doc, You can also try the `volatile-ttl` policy instead of `allkeys-lru`; that's closer to what you may want

Comment: Exactly. Also look into the new LFU mode introduced in v4

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script to do something like this to remove all keys in a week (python):

```
for key in redis.keys('*'):
    if redis.ttl(key) == -1:
        redis.expire(key, 604800)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your idea is similar to mine - expect mine is writing the script in LUA. However out of interest, is there an alternative to polling this script for x number of minutes?

Comment: careful, the keys command runs in O(n) where n is the number of keys in your db. It will destroy redis performance. The docs warn against using it in application code: https://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: Thanks guys. Useful information. I'm assuming that having a polling script is acceptable providing that SCAN is used rather than KEYS.

Comment: @rm12345 I'm not convinced of this approach. Periodically scanning all keys is not very efficient (though better than using the keys command). Maybe better to set the expire to every key just after creating them?
 Assumning that you are starting with an empty db and are not interested in [other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600062/2754507)

Comment: @MarioTrucco setting an expiry on a key when added is what I originally preferred...just that I'm trying to avoid setting the EXPIRE on the Java side and prefer to set it on the REDIS server side. Unless you have any ideas on how it could be done? (after looking on the web, I couldn't see such info)

Comment: @rm12345 I'll link again to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600062/2754507) (sorry): It's about configuring a cache policy in the redis server. May not be exactly what you want but should get quite close

Comment: Thanks @MarioTrucco

Answer (score 0):

In redis-cli you can do things like the following:

```
SETEX keyhere seconds valuehere //nnog's example above
SET keyhere valuehere EX seconds   //extended version
```

It comes in handy when handling realtime data.

However, keep in mind that Redis might deprecate `SETEX` in the future.

According to them:

Note: Since the SET command options can replace SETNX, SETEX, PSETEX, it is possible that in future versions of Redis these three commands will be deprecated and finally removed.

Link here: https://redis.io/commands/set